# Passing hash key to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have this code in Rails 2.x:

```
<div class="label-field-pair">
    <label><%= t('select_a_course_batch') %></label>
    <div class="text-input-bg"> <%= select :fees_submission, :batch_id, @batches.map { |c| [c.full_name, c.id] },
        {:prompt => "#{t('select_a_batch')}"},
        {:onChange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:action => "update_fees_collection_dates_voucher"}, :with => "'batch_id='+value")}"}%> </div>
```

for the onChange action.. I want to pass the hash key (c.fullname) to the remote update_fees_collection_dates_voucher controller instead of the hash value (c.id) .. Replacing "'batch_id='+value" with "'batch_id='+key" doesnt seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this working?

```
{:onChange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:action => "update_fees_collection_dates_voucher"}, :with => "'batch_id='+ $(this).html()}"}%>
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't work.. I'm not sure how $(this).html() would translate into the hash key .. can you elaborate on how this works? THanks..

Comment: Which JS lib are you using prototype or jquery?